# Benefits of using OneWay over a Response/Request contract in WCF for void methods

Tags: .net, wcf

Will it make any difference if I change the operation contract of methods having no return value by  `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]`

I know the differences between both (OneWay and Response/Request) MEP(Message Excahnge Pattern).

but want to know if I change this will it boost the performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will - and **more importantly boost scalability** too. Client is released as soon as call is taken up at the server and client does not have to wait until processing finishes. This helps the resources at both client and server to be released as soon as possible.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730149%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702379/queuing-in-oneway-wcf-messages-using-windows-service-and-sql-server ?